# Prove $a\leq b$ or $b \leq a$ in Coq

Tags: logic, computer-science

I am reading the software foundations for [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/), and one property that I would like to prove is the excluded middle for $\leq$. The definitions are the following

```
Inductive nat : Type :=
| O
| S (n : nat).


Inductive bool : Type :=
  | true
  | false.

Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match n with
  | O => true
  | S n' =>
      match m with
      | O => false
      | S m' => leb n' m'
      end
end.
Notation "x <=? y" := (leb x y) (at level 70).
Theorem EQEM: forall n m, n <=? m = true \/ n <=? m = false.
```

The proof is easy but how to implement it in Coq? Since the function is to type bool and terminates, the output is always a bool, and that should complete the proof. Induction seems to lead nowhere, although an infinite descent argument also  concludes the matter trivially, perhaps there is something I missed...

Comment: Universal statements in Peano arithmetic are usually proved by induction, this case you need a double induction, on both $n$ and $m$. It's basically the repetition of the definition of `leb`.

Comment: You have described anti-symmetry of $\leq$ in the title, but some sort of "excluded middle" in the Coq code. I'm not familiar with Coq, in general it's true that for all booleans you have $b=\text{true}$ or $b=\text{false}$ which should have a short proof via pattern matching - mostly a matter of knowing Coq syntax. Anti-symmetry of $\leq$ is less trivial, but the key point is that it's trivial if $n=0$ or $m=0$ and otherwise you can use that `(leb (S n) (S m))` is judgmentally equal to `(leb n m)` - so the proof is by matching into cases on if either $n$ or $m$ is zero.

Comment: @Berci yes, strong double induction does work. But to prove strong induction principle, some properties of $\leq$ are needed.

Comment: Are you able to prove $x = 0 \lor x \ne 0$ ?

Comment: @DanielV Yes, that is no problem.

Comment: @DanielV Ok, I got it now, hehe. Indeed it is possible to substitute...

Still I wonder since Coq is supposedly constructive. How does it "know" that the function always terminates and thus has the appropriate type? User does not need to prove that... (and yes I am aware that prim rec functions terminate, but it would still be nice to prove it in Coq). So... I would definite prefer the double induction proof.

Comment: @Dole IIRC CoC introduces some silent assumptions when you make an inductive definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here are the answers, thank you for the very helpful comments. First, as was pointed out, a regular induction can solve the problem. Some attention must be paid to the order of operations, it is possible to get stuck.

```
Theorem EQEM: forall n m, n <=? m = true \/ n <=? m = false.
induction n. intros m. destruct m. left. reflexivity.
left. reflexivity. intros m. induction m. right.
reflexivity. specialize (IHn m). simpl. exact IHn.
Qed.
```

However, the substitution proof works as well.

```
Theorem LEMB: forall b: bool, b = true \/ b = false.
Proof. destruct b. left. reflexivity. right. reflexivity. Qed.

Theorem EQEM: forall n m, n <=? m = true \/ n <=? m = false.
Proof. pose LEMB as H. intros n m. specialize (H (n <=? m)).
exact H. Qed.
```